# VirtualBox | Convert from .vdi .vbox(windows) to .ova .ovf(linux)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine

I'm using Debian 8 and i moved my Virtual Machine from Windows to Debian 8. How I shoud make it work ? It types

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Win.
The VM session was closed before any attempt to power it on
```

How to convert .vdi .vbox to .ova .ovf, soo i can use them in Linux ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need .ova or .ovf, VirtualBox on Linux uses the same formats and you can directly use your .vdi and .vbox files.

I had that same error and it was caused by VirtualBox not being able to write to the VM folder (the one with the .vdi and .vbox files), that can happen when moving things between computers or different OSs. Changed the folder permissions and it worked.